# How can we derive the asymptotic expansion for the second derivative of the gamma-function?

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function, polygamma

We can expression the first derivative of the gamma function as:
$$\Gamma'(s) \sim -\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{6\gamma^2+\pi^2}{12}+O(s)$$ but what about the second derivative? I do not know how to approach the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. For $\Gamma(s)$, this is correct, right?: $\Gamma(s) \sim \frac{1}{s}-\gamma+O(s)$

Comment: I suggest equations [DLMF 5.7.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E1) and 5.7.2 gives you all you need.

Comment: Can't you just differentiate the given expression for $\Gamma'(s)$? $\Gamma$ is meromorphic, so $\Gamma''(s)\sim \frac{2}{s^3}$ for $s\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obtain the expansion of any derivative of $\Gamma(s)$ using its own expansion and derivating term wise
$$\Gamma(s)=\frac{1}{s}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) s+\frac{1}{6} 
   \left(-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}+\psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)s^2+\frac{1}{24} 
   \left(8 \gamma  \zeta (3)+\gamma ^4+\gamma ^2 \pi ^2+\frac{3 \pi
   ^4}{20}\right)s^3+\frac{ \left(-40 \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) \zeta (3)-288
   \zeta (5)-12 \gamma ^5-20 \gamma ^3 \pi ^2-9 \gamma  \pi
   ^4\right)}{1440}s^4+O\left(s^5\right)$$ and truncate the result to $O(s)$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

- Start from [the explicit formula for $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula)
- Expand $\Gamma'(s)/\Gamma(s)+\frac1s$ in power series, the coefficients are $(-1)^{k+1}\zeta(k+1)$,
- Integrate to get the power series of $\log \Gamma(s)+\log s$
- Exponentiate to get the power series of $s \Gamma(s)$
- Differentiate the obtained Laurent series of $\Gamma(s)$ to obtain the Laurent series of its derivatives.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!